# react native ios build fails with error - 'EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, project, react-native-cli

react native ios build fails with error

```
'EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h' file not found
```

file used in AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h>  <--- here
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <UMCore/UMAppDelegateWrapper.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <RCTBridgeDelegate, EXUpdatesAppControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Anyone solutions?

Answer (score 7):

This error means that Xcode is unable to find the package that is supposed to be in your development pod folder ( at least that is the case for me)

Few points to double check:

1. Ensure that you have your `react-native-unimodules` installed and is reflected in your `package.json`.
2. Ensure that `expo-updates` package is installed. Else run `npm install expo-updates --save` or use the `yarn` command.
3. In your `Podfile`, ensure you have this line :  `use_unimodules!`

After ensuring both are there, run `cd ios` followed by `pod install` to install the EX modules. The modules should be in your 'Development Pods' folder. Lastly,
rebuild your xcode project. These ways work for me. Hopefully, they can be of some help.

Comment: `use_unimodules!` is key but just adding it without the appropriate require_relative  at the top of the file will fail. See here for a good example of a full Podfile. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65084966/1131990 I used this and it resolved my issue

Comment: I get "use_unimodules!" not found in my Podfile

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as Kakoma says it is very necessary to place the route:

`require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods'`

at the beginning of the Podfile to avoid the following error:

`Invalid Podfile file: undefined method use_unimodules! ' for # <Pod :: Podfile:`

Comment: This is necessary and worked thanks!